# Quel est l'équivalent du québécisme « ayoye » en français général etc. ?

Tags: usage, québec, interjections, onomatopées

L'interjection ou onomatopée « ayoye » [ajɔj] est un québécisme ([*Usito*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/ayoye), attesté en 1912 [*TLFQ*](https://www.tlfq.org/) ; [*Wiktionnair*e](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ayoye), [*Offenbach/Boulet*](https://youtube.com/watch?v=MvXuyIw6OCU) ; différentes graphies [*aioulle*](https://www.tlfq.org/fonds/citation/410237), [*ayoi*](https://www.tlfq.org/fonds/citation/354979) etc.) basé sur la contraction de [*aïe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a%C3%AFe) et de [*ouille*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ouille/0), pour exprimer soit la douleur, soit l'étonnement, la surprise, l'admiration ou encore l'exaspération etc.

- Est-on familier avec le fait qu'il s'agit d'un québécisme à l'extérieur du Québec ou autrement dit est-ce
  une marque reconnaissable du français québécois ?
- Est-ce généralement *aïe* ou *ouille* qu'on considère équivalent en
  français général pour exprimer la douleur et peut-on employer l'un ou
  l'autre pour marquer aussi l'étonnement, la surprise, l'admiration ou
  encore l'exaspération ?

Answer (score 2):

Je ne connaissais pas ***ayoye*** avant de lire ta question mais je l'avais peut-être déjà entendu sans le remarquer. Le mot est phonétiquement trop proche de *Aille-aille* et *ouille-ouille* pour qu'il soit perçu comme quelque chose de nouveau.

Dans tous les contextes où une douleur ou un risque matériel est présent, *ouille-ouille* fait bien sûr l'affaire.

Sinon, je ne vois pas d'expression regroupant « étonnement, surprise, admiration ou encore exaspération » à moins d'aller piocher dans d'autres régionalismes comme ***atche***, ***atche de***, ***fatche***, ***fan***, ***fan de chichourle***, ***boudiou*** qu'on pourrait entendre à Marseille.

Answer (score 1):

À ma connaissance on n'utilise ni « ayoye », ni « aioulle » ni « ayoi ».

Les deux servent à exprimer la douleur (petites douleurs). Je ne les ai jamais entendus pour autre chose que la douleur, bien que parfois il s'agisse d'exprimer la douleur ressentie par quelqu'un d'autre lorsqu'on est témoin d'un incident qui cause de la douleur.

Une combinaison de ces deux onomatopées est possible en français de France.

- [pinterest](https://www.pinterest.fr/pin/ae-ouillea-fait-mal--510947520199626470/)  aïe, ouille...ça fait mal !

On peut même trouver la combinaison sans virgule où la première onomatopée est répétée.

- [Aie aie ouille !!!](https://forum.francelymphomeespoir.fr/t/aie-aie-ouille/8910)

Double répétition !

- [Aïe aïe aïe ouille orteil écrasé!!!](https://www.chevalannonce.com/forums-5089099-aie-aie-aie-ouille-orteil-ecrase?p=2)
- [Aïe aïe aïe… Ouille !!!](https://blogoth67.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/aie-aie-aie-ouille/)

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Quelques spécialistes sont probablement conscient de ça, mais étant donné que l'influence du Québec dans le monde francophone ne peut être que minime il ne peut pas exister beaucoup de personnes conscientes de ça ; un féru du cinéma canadien ou de la littérature saura cela, par exemple. J'ai passé une vie à ne pas être conscient de l'accent canadien ; je n'ai commencé à le découvrir que dernièrement. Si le Canada avait une industrie du cinéma d'un aussi grand succès que les EUA il y aurait peut être une chance, mais même aujourd'hui qui sait que « whao » vient des EUA ?

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Ce foyer d'activités variées est très certainement centré sur la culture anglaise/américaine; il n'y a qu'une dizaine de millions de québécois ; je ne vois pas comment leur culture française  pourrait être aussi influente ; elle ne semble pas l'être en tous cas par ce qui en parait dans les médias en France.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Le [canadarm](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadarm), du Québec ? Agence Spatiale Canadienne, tout l'état.